# Swift Package storyboard localization

Tags: ios, swift, localization, storyboard, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to create a Swift Package with a localized `Storyboard` inside (following the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/localizing_package_resources)). Let's say my package manifest is:

```swift
// swift-tools-version: 5.6
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    defaultLocalization: "en",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyPackage",
            targets: ["MyPackage"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyPackage",
            dependencies: [])
    ]
)
```

I want my package to contain a localized `Storyboard`, so I created a structure like this:

[image]

where `main.strings` in `en.lproj` is:

```
"T63-i3-Tqi.text" = "Hello World";
```

and `main.strings` in `it.lproj` is:

```
"T63-i3-Tqi.text" = "Ciao a tutti!";
```

Then I link this package to an app and I set the app localization to both `english` and `italian`. Unfortunately, though, when I change the app language nothing changes. I mean, the app always takes the english localization of the `Storyboard`.
Can you help me? Thanks.